# prepareforsegue integer value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, int

Just a little question. I have a root view controller (`AufnahmeIstTableViewController`) and a detail view controller (`AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController`)

I also have an `int` called `istAufnahmeInt`. When the user selects `row 1` on my root view controller, then the value of my `int` is set to `0`. When `row 2` is pressed the value is set to 1, ... .

In my `prepareForSegue` method, I have the following code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailView"])
{
    AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *controller = (AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.istAufnahmeInt = //What should I enter here? ;
}
}
```

So, what do I have to enter where my comment is to get the value of my `istAufnahmeInt`?

I use Storyboards.

For completion: Here's my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *categories = [[AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController alloc]init];

if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Gesetze"])
    categories.istAufnahmeInt = 0;

if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Messmittel"])
    categories.istAufnahmeInt = 1;

if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Dritte"])
    categories.istAufnahmeInt = 2;

[categories setTitle:[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need to do is:

```
controller.istAufnahmeInt = categories.istAufnahmeInt;
```

And the only thing you need to change is to make:

```
AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *categories
```

into a `@property`

That is to say:

```
@property (strong) AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *categories;
```

declared in the right place in your .h or .m file.

Comment: ok, but when i do this i get the error warning 'use of undeclared identifier categories

Comment: right... your "`prepareForSegue:`" method knows nothing of "`categories`" until you make "`categories`" a property.

Comment: because categories is only declared in my didselectrowatindexpathmethod

Comment: not if you declare it as a property; or if you don't want to do that, declare an integer property via "`@property (readwrite) NSInteger istAufnahmeInt;`".

Comment: do i have to declare "@property (strong) AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *categories;" in my  AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h file or in my AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h file? Do I need to synthesize it?

Comment: ok, so when I add it as a property, I get warnings at my didselectrowatindexpath method

Comment: Do you need more details?

Comment: you're getting warnings probably because you didn't remove the old "`categories`" declaration in your "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`" method.  And if you did create a property, refer to it using "`self.categories` instead of "`categories`".

Comment: Ok, but now I get everywhere my istAufnahmeInt is, the warning:  Property 'istAufnahmeInt' not found on object of type 'AufnahmeIstTableViewController'

Comment: What do I now have to do?

Comment: Make sure you add the "`@property` in the right place.

Comment: I did it in my AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h file and then synthesized it.